# Hahn-Banach in dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let us take a subspace $V \subset X^*$ of the topological dual space and a linear functional
$\varphi \colon V \to \mathbb R$. We assume that $\varphi$ is continuous w.r.t. the weak-$*$ topology on $V$. Thus, it is continuous w.r.t. the strong topology, i.e., bounded. Hence, we can use

- Hahn-Banach in the Banach space $X^*$ to obtain an extension $\varphi_1 \colon X^* \to \mathbb R$ with $\|\varphi_1\| = \|\varphi\|$. However, $\varphi_1$ might not be weak-$*$ continuous.
- Hahn-Banach in the tvs $X^*$ equipped with the weak-$*$ topology to obtain an extension $\varphi_2 \colon X^* \to \mathbb R$ which is weak-$*$ continuous. However, $\|\varphi_2\| > \|\varphi\|$ might happen.

> Is it possible to combine both approaches, i.e., does there exist an extension $\varphi_3 \colon X^* \to \mathbb R$ with $\|\varphi_3\| = \|\varphi\|$ **and** $\varphi_3$ is weak-$*$ continuous?

I doubt that this is always possible, but I do not have any counterexample.

Comment: How do you conclude that a functional which is continuous in the weak* topology is continuous in the strong topology (without further assumtions on $X$)?

Comment: @Maksim Convergence in the strong topology implies convergence in weak* topology. No extra assumption on $X$ is needed.

Comment: By weak$*$-continuity, $\varphi$ is an evaluation in some $x_0\in X$, but this point is not unique. I guess that $\|\varphi\|=\inf\{\|x_0+z\|: z\in V^\perp\}$ where $V^\perp=\{x\in X: x^*(x)=0$ for all $x^*\in V\}$ is the annihilator ov $V$. For a counterexample one could try to find $V$ such that this infimum is not a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple counterexample. We choose $X = c_0$ (null sequences), thus $X^* = \ell^1$. We choose the subspace
$$
V = \left\{ y \in \ell^1 \;\middle|\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty y(i) = 0\right\} $$
and
$$\varphi(y) := y(1).$$

One can check that
$$\|\varphi\| = \sup\{ \varphi(y) \;\mid\; y \in V, \|y\|\le1\}= 1/2.$$
Further, the sequence $e_1 \in X$ is the only weak-* continuous extension of $\varphi$, but $\|e_1\| = 1$.